Authlib for Flask response state from Google OAuth missing
I'm currently building a flask based web app - and using the Lepture/authlib library.
I've read that using a randomly generated state object or variable in the request, is best practice for avoiding/mitigating CSRF attacks - and am trying to implement it.
There are similar questions to mine here, here, and here though none of these are quite what I'm looking for (I think).
I am able to authorize normally in my dev environment, and redirect to pages that require a user to be logged on - but am unable to appropriately validate state, by collecting the state object from google's response.
Does the authlib flask extension abstract state management across providers or have I missed something somewhere? My code is below;
Login Route
@bp.route("/login")
def login():
    oauth = current_app.extensions["authlib.integrations.flask_client"]
    google = oauth.create_client("google")
    redirect_uri = url_for("auth.authorize", _external=True)
    state = generate_state()
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri, state=state)

Authorize Route
Just adds user details to the DB for now
@bp.route("/authorize")
def authorize():
    oauth = current_app.extensions["authlib.integrations.flask_client"]
    google = oauth.create_client("google")
    db = get_db()
    # TODO: Work through oauth2 doco to figure out where you need to use a token at all for simple logon
    # token = google.authorize_access_token()
    resp = google.get("userinfo")
    resp.raise_for_status()
    profile = resp.json()
    name = profile["given_name"]
    google_id = profile["id"]
    #  -- DB checks, loads or creates user & saves pertinent details to session -- removed for brevity
    session["profile"] = profile
    session["user_id"] = user_id
    current_app.logger.info(f"User {name} with id {user_id} logged in.")
    return redirect(url_for("auth.callback"))

Callback Route - here's where I think I'm stuck
@bp.route("/callback")
def callback():
    # Retrieve state from query parameter and session
    # TODO: Implement state validation - currently unable to get state from response
    state_query = request.get['state']
    state_session = session.pop("oauth_state", None)
    # Validate state
    if not state_query or state_query != state_session:
        return "State validation failed.", 400  # Or handle as appropriate
    # Redirect to the URL the user originally requested
    redirect_url = session.pop("redirect_back_to", url_for("index"))
    return redirect(redirect_url)

TIA!
